# Passing parameters to shell script from a python program

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I would like to call a shell script from my python script. I need to pass 3 parameters/arguments to the shell script. I am able to call the shell script (that is in the same directory as that of the python script), but having some issue with the parameter passing

```
from subprocess import call

// other code here.
line = "Hello"
// Here is how I call the shell command
call (["./myscript.sh", "/usr/share/file1.txt", ""/usr/share/file2.txt", line], shell=True)

In my shell script I have this
#!/bin/sh

echo "Parameters are $1 $2 $3"
...

Unfortunately parameters are not getting passed correctly.

I get this message:

Parameters are 

None of the parameter values are passed in the script
```

Comment: Works fine with `shell=False`, the recommended use -- why do you think you need `shell=True` instead?!

Comment: You don't want a list argument with `shell=True` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
call ("./myscript.sh /usr/share/file1.txt /usr/share/file2.txt "+line, shell=True)
```

When you are using `shell=True` you can directly pass the command as if passing on shell directly.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that and it works fine except for the last argument. I see this in my script:
Parameters are: /usr/share/file1.txt /usr/share/file2.txt line
I would like to have:
/usr/share/file1.txt /usr/share/file2.txt Hello

Comment: Yes, I did this:
cmd = "./myscript.sh /usr/share/file1.txt /usr/share/file2.txt" + " " + line

call([cmd],shell=True). That worked fine.

Comment: [`shell=True` is unnecessary here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28597184/4279). Also, it may break if `line` contains shell metacharacters such as `$\`!`.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `shell=True` (you might need to make `myscript.sh` executable: `$ chmod +x myscript.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

line = "Hello world!"
check_call(["./myscript.sh", "/usr/share/file1.txt", "/usr/share/file2.txt", 
            line])
```

[Do not use a list argument and `shell=True` together](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347).